# Separating white space in a dictionary [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a concordance program and finished but when I get the dictionary value of a certain word, I get this sort of dictionary:
{'self evident': 2} where I really want {'self': 2, 'evident': 2}

Is there a way to do this, remove the white space in a dictionary value, separate the keys and then copy the value associated with the key?

Thank you for the help, let me know if I can clear my question up, sorry if it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
dic = {'self evident a b c': 2,"d e f":3}
result = {}
for k,v in dic.items():
    for new_key in k.split():
        result[new_key] = v
print(result)
```

result:

```
{'self': 2, 'evident': 2, 'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 3}
```

Comment: By default `split()` will split a string by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the dict keys and split on ' '

```
aDict = {'self evident': 2}
keys = aDict.keys()
new_dict = {}
for k in keys:
    for element in k.split():
        new_dict[element] = aDict.get(k, None)
```

Comment: By default `split()` will split a string by spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this example using `dict-comprehension`

```
dictEx = {'self evident':2}
formated = {keyEx:v for k,v in dictEx.items() for keyEx in k.split()}
```